# How to create table in laravel without created_at and Updated_at column using migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration

Can anyone know how to create Table in laravel without created_at and Updated_at Column in table using a migration.
I try this Following code but it's still create created_at and Updated_at column in table:-

Migration Laravel :-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateNewusersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('newusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('name');
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('phone_no');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('newusers');
    }
}
```

Comment: add `$table->timestamps();` to `up` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your model

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Comment: Oh Now i understand that first i have to create model and add this line than after create migration table.